# Acceptance test Redirecting to specific URL

Tags: ember.js, acceptance-testing

I created an Acceptance test on ember-cli, in order to check when a user is on a URL and then clicks on the "Cancel" button on that page, the page should be redirected to other URL.

When running the test I'm getting this error:

> "Promise rejected during Redirects to previous URL if cancel button is
>   clicked: Element .close-button not found".

But I have that element on my template. Could someone suggest me what I'm missing here or suggest me a documentation I can read in order to solved this error?.

This is my acceptance test:

```
import { test } from 'qunit';
import moduleForAcceptance from '/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | test/company');
test('Redirects to previous URL if cancel button is clicked', function() {
    return visit('test/company/add').then(function(){
      return click('.close-button');
    }).then(function(assert){
      assert.equal(currentURL(), 'test/company');
    });
});
```

I tried this test too, but I keep getting similar error:

```
test('Redirects to previous URL if cancel button is clicked', function(assert) {
  visit('/test/company/add');
  click ('.close-button');
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/test/company');
  });
});
```

This is the error:

> Error: Element .close-button not found.

This is part of the template where I have the cancel button( add.hbs)

```
<div class="form-add">
    <a href="#" class="close-button" {{action 'cancel'}}>Close</a>
</div>
```

This is the controller, where the action 'cancel' is defined:

```
actions: {
    cancel() {
       if (this.get('isSaved')) {
           return;
       }
         this.transitionToRoute('test/company');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting click inside your andThen() in your second approach?

Answer (score 2):

Visit and click are the test helpers which will return a promise.Usually you will execute the further testing once your promises are resolved.

Try doing this:

```
test('Redirects to previous URL if cancel button is clicked', function(assert) {
  visit('/test/company/add');  
  andThen(()=>{
    click ('.close-button');
    andThen(()=>{
        assert.equal(currentURL(), '/test/company');
    })  
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your code but I'm still getting the same error. I don't know what's else to do. It can't find that element on the page.